# Setting location of Angular production JavaScript bundles in index.html

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular-cli

In Angular 6 app, I have a custom JavaScript file which I would like to load after minified bundles created by `ng build --prod`.

**The desired output**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- ... -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- ... -->
    <script src="runtime.06daa30a2963fa413676.js"></script>
    <script src="polyfills.f6ae3e8b63939c618130.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts.3093c8de343a90aee8a5.js"></script>
    <script src="main.2f79061174841f85d990.js"></script>

    <script src="customScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**The problem**

By default, JavaScript bundles are added at the end of the `<body>` tag, which makes the `customScript.js` loads before them.

Is it possible to set in which line of the index.html Angular CLI should add script bundles created using Angular CLI or at least put them before the custom script?

Comment: Try to add your custom js file in angular cli file as below."scripts": [
    "customScript.js"
] 
https://medium.com/@davembush/adding-css-and-javascript-to-an-angular-cli-project-2b843a8283f3

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't. The intention is to keep this file outside the bundled application and keep it only on the server.